# How to implement a queue array for music bot

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm an amateur and I have this music bot setup but not sure how to implement a queue feature which would add videos in an array to be played after one song is finished. Do I have to reformat the code so that there is a queue function before everything or is there a simple fix?

Below is my code,

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    description: 'Joins and plays video from youtube',
    async execute(message, args) {
        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;

        if(!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('Join a channel to play a song');
        const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if(!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send('You dont have permission to use this function');
        if(!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('You dont have permission to use this function');
        if(!args.length) return message.channel.send('You need to send a second argument');


        //Set up play function for link
        const validURL = (str) =>{
            var regex = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%!\-\/]))?/;
            if(!regex.test(str)){
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        if(validURL(args[0])){
            const connection = await voiceChannel.join();
            const stream = ytdl(args[0], {filter: 'audioonly'});

            connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
            .on('finish', () =>{
                voiceChannel.leave();
                message.channel.send('Leaving Channel!');
            });

            await message.reply('Now Playing Link')

            return

        }
        
        //Set up play function for youtube search w/ keywords
        const connection = await voiceChannel.join();

        const videoFinder = async (query) => {
            const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);

            return (videoResult.videos.length > 1)? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
        }

        const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));

        if(video){
            const stream = ytdl(video.url, {filter: 'audioonly'});
            connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
            .on('finish', () =>{
                voiceChannel.leave();
            });

            await message.reply(`Now Playing ***${video.title}*** ${video.duration}*** ${video.thumbnail}`)
        } else {
            message.channel.send('No video results found.');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    description: 'Joins and plays video from youtube',
    queues: {},
    voiceConnections: {},
    execute() {
      if (!this.voiceConnections[guildId]) {
        // setup voiceConnections[guildId]

        this.voiceConnections[guildId].on('finish', () => {
          this.voiceConnections[guildId].play(this.queues[guildId].pop())
        }
      } 

      if (track already playing in voice connection) {
        this.queues[guildId].push(newTrackDetails);
      } else {
        // play the track
      }  
    }
}
```

Some pseudocode. Idea: Each guild has its own queue and voice channel connection. The queue object format looks something like {'guildId1': [...queue tracks details here]}